# Get Rid of Meta Key Gnome

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts

When I attempt to set key bindings in Gnome that use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, Gnome also includes the <kbd>Meta</kbd> key. For instance when trying to set a keybinding to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> and pressing only those keys, Gnome shows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>. This causes no direct loss of functionality or anything as it seems the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is sending both the <kbd>Alt</kbd> and the <kbd>Meta</kbd> signals. How can I get rid of this extra <kbd>Meta</kbd> signal?

Also I have tried this with both the left and right <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys.